# Can't get my binding with nested viewModels to work with objects instead of strings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following issue, and have made a small fiddle for it to explain my problem.

I have the following viewModels in my code:

```
var InnerModel = function(n){
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(n);
    self.selectedOption = ko.observable('Option2');
};

var OuterModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.inners = new ko.observableArray([new InnerModel('A'), new InnerModel('B')]);
    self.options = ['Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'];
};

var viewModel = new OuterModel();

ko.applyBindings( viewModel);
```

In addition I have the following relevant HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: inners">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p data-bind="text: selectedOption"></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: $root.options,
                                   value: selectedOption"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This works as expected. The select box starts off with Option2 as selected, and when I select a new option in the select box then InnerModel.selectedOption changes it's value as well. So all is good here.

But in my case, I need the options list in the OuterModel to be more than an array of strings, so I changed it to this:

```
self.options = [{ name: 'Option1', value: 1},{ name: 'Option2', value: 1},{ name: 'Option3', value: 1}];
```

Then in the HTML I added `optionsText: 'name'` to the data-binding on the select box.

The select box now still shows the three valid options, but the link towards self.selectedOption does not work anymore (as expected) since Knockout will have a hard time matching the text 'Option2' to one of the options contained within the OuterModel.options list.

Any way I can change InnerModel.selectedOption to make the binding still work as before? Sending an reference from OuterModel to InnerModel with an actual option from the array is not an option as they are quite seperated in the real application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code it will work as excpected.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: inners">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p data-bind="text: selectedOption"></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: $root.options,
                optionsText: 'name',
                optionsValue: 'value',
                value: selectedOption"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

javascript:

```
var InnerModel = function(n){
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(n);
    self.selectedOption = ko.observable(2);
};



var OuterModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.inners = new ko.observableArray([new InnerModel('A'), new InnerModel('B')]);
    self.options = [{ name: 'Option1', value: 1},{ name: 'Option2', value: 2},{ name: 'Option3', value: 3}];
};

var viewModel = new OuterModel();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

If you want to bind objects to the select-tag you have to bind also the optionValue property. And because knockout always selects the predefined selected value by the value attribute in your html the must be the self.selectedOption a valid value of the options obect array.

Comment: optionsValue is what I was missing. Now it works just fine. Thanks a lot for your help :)